# How can I get this text to always appear inside the div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this example numberplate to show up inside the div. What changes to the styling do I need to make to ensure this works on most devices?

```html
<div style="text-align: center;"><strong><a style="position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000!important;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: .86em;
    width: 13.55544em;
    height: 2.57519em;
    padding: .1282em;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(255,205,255,.5);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(rgba(255,255,255,.03125)),color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,.03125)),color-stop(51%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,155,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left,rgba(255,225,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), inset 0 -0.25em 1em -0.4em rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0.05em 0.192em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25),inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5),inset 0 -.25em 1em -.4em rgba(0,0,0,.25),inset 0 .5em .5em -.4em rgba(255,255,255,.5),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 .05em .192em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), inset 0 -0.25em 1em -0.4em rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0.05em 0.192em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: .11752em;
    -moz-border-radius: .11752em;
    border-radius: .11752em; background-color:#fc1;">
    <strong style="font-size:30px; font-family: Arial;">NU69 REG</strong>
  </a>
</div>
```

The text seems to just show up after the actual div, e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTYyq.png when I'm sending this via email.

In most browsers, the text still appears inside the div.

Comment: Your HTML isn't correct (you're missing a `</strong>`). I would start by correcting this and see the issue is resolved. Oftentimes a browser will "correct" your HTML, the results of which can move elements outside of their intended parents. Better yet, just give the link `font-weight: bold` and ditch all the `<strong>` tags entirely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<div style="text-align: center;margin:0 auto;"><strong style="display:table;margin:0 auto;"><a style="position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #000!important;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: .86em;
width: 13.55544em;
height: 2.57519em;
padding: .1282em;
text-decoration: none!important;
text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(255,205,255,.5);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(rgba(255,255,255,.03125)),color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,.03125)),color-stop(51%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,155,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left,rgba(255,225,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), inset 0 -0.25em 1em -0.4em rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0.05em 0.192em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25),inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5),inset 0 -.25em 1em -.4em rgba(0,0,0,.25),inset 0 .5em .5em -.4em rgba(255,255,255,.5),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 .05em .192em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), inset 0 -0.25em 1em -0.4em rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0.05em 0.192em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-webkit-border-radius: .11752em;
-moz-border-radius: .11752em;
border-radius: .11752em; background-color:#fc1;">
<strong style="font-size:30px; font-family: Arial;">NU69 REG</strong>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: without using flex you can make display: table and child should be display:table-cell.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Consider adding context. This answer is a game of spot-the-difference.

Answer (score 0):

use CSS `flex` property

I am doing it the same way as you use the style. You are trying to place a content vertically and horizontally middle.

```
justify-content:center; // palce content horizontally center
align-items:center; // palce item vertically center.
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000!important;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 13.55544em;
    height: 2.57519em;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(255,205,255,.5);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(rgba(255,255,255,.03125)),color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,.03125)),color-stop(51%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,155,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left,rgba(255,225,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), inset 0 -0.25em 1em -0.4em rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0.05em 0.192em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25),inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5),inset 0 -.25em 1em -.4em rgba(0,0,0,.25),inset 0 .5em .5em -.4em rgba(255,255,255,.5),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 .05em .192em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), inset 0 -0.25em 1em -0.4em rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0.05em 0.192em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: .11752em;
    -moz-border-radius: .11752em;
    border-radius: .11752em; background-color:#fc1;">
    <strong style="font-size:30px; font-family: Arial;">NU69 REG</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: How does this address or fix OP's issue? You haven't explained why OP's text is appearing outside of his button entirely (see screenshot). I don't think the issue is related to CSS, so modifying it to be flex instead doesn't seem like it'll fix anything. Not to mention, using `flex` in an email is bad advice, as it isn't supported by most prominent mail clients (like Outlook).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the markup I would recommend using. This will make sure the anchor stays inside the `<div>`, and also that the button is centered.

Changes I made
Outer `<div>`: Removed `text-align: center;` and added `font-weight: bold;` to do away with `<strong>` tags.
`<a>`: changed to `display: table;` in order to keep child element centered.
Inner `<div>`: Changed it to a `<span>` and used `display: table-cell;`

```
<div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
<a style="position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000!important;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: .86em;
    width: 13.55544em;
    height: 2.57519em;
    padding: .1282em;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(255,205,255,.5);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(rgba(255,255,255,.03125)),color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,.03125)),color-stop(51%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,155,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left,rgba(255,225,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 0,rgba(255,255,255,.03125) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.03125) 51%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), inset 0 -0.25em 1em -0.4em rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0.05em 0.192em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25),inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5),inset 0 -.25em 1em -.4em rgba(0,0,0,.25),inset 0 .5em .5em -.4em rgba(255,255,255,.5),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 .05em .192em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), inset 0 -0.25em 1em -0.4em rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0.05em 0.192em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: .11752em;
    -moz-border-radius: .11752em;
    border-radius: .11752em; background-color:#fc1;">
    <span style="font-size:30px; font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: middle;">NU69 REG</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are easier when you simplify the markup and apply styles that ensure certain appearance.

A combination of no `padding-top` or `padding-bottom`, with matched `height` and `line-height` will ensure the label text of the button sits perfectly vertically centered:

```
  /* match height and line-height for the vertical centering */
  height: 2.57519em;
  line-height: 2.57519em;

  /* no padding top or bottom */
  padding: 0 .1282em;
```

```css
.my-button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 13.55544em;
  /* match height and line-height for the vertical centering */
  height: 2.57519em;
  line-height: 2.57519em;
  /* no padding top or bottom */
  padding: 0 .1282em;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(255, 205, 255, .5);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, .03125)), color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .03125)), color-stop(51%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03125)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, rgba(255, 255, 255, .03125) 0, rgba(255, 155, 255, .03125) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03125) 51%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, rgba(255, 225, 255, .03125) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, .03125) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03125) 51%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, rgba(255, 255, 255, .03125) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, .03125) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03125) 51%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(255, 255, 255, .03125) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, .03125) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .03125) 51%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset 0 -0.25em 1em -0.4em rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0.05em 0.192em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset 0 -.25em 1em -.4em rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 0 .5em .5em -.4em rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 .05em .192em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset 0 -0.25em 1em -0.4em rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0.05em 0.192em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-border-radius: .11752em;
  -moz-border-radius: .11752em;
  border-radius: .11752em;
  background-color: #fc1;
}
```

```html
<a class="my-button">NU69 REG</a>
```